# Python, compare if a Float is close to an Integer

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, integer, comparison

I'm coding a program to analyse sentiments in Tweets. I want to perform a test where I have a dataset of Tweets like this :

```
label,text  
0, blabla  
1, blablabla  
0, blablablabla
```

where label is the polarity (0 negative and 1 positive) and text is the Tweet. Now my program isn't returning 0 or 1 but values between 0.0 and 1.0, so it may be 0.33.

To perform the test I looked for `compare almost equal values` and I found out [numpy isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) but for a reason there is something wrong.

Let me show you some example I got:

```
mycode: 1.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.8 dataset:0
mycode: 0.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.5 dataset:0
mycode: 1.0 dataset:0
mycode: 1.0 dataset:0
mycode: 1.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.66 dataset:0
mycode: 0.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.33 dataset:0
mycode: 1.0 dataset:0
mycode: 0.66 dataset:0
```

so then I did :

```py
# Analyse each Tweet
for index, row in df.iloc[:15].iterrows():
   test = Feel(row['text'])
   if np.isclose(test.emotions().get('positivity'), row['label'], rtol=0.8):
       correct = correct + 1
   print("mycode: " + str(test.emotions().get('positivity')) + " dataset:" + str(row['label']));
```

and I got a total of correct ones of : 5 but I should get at least 9 correct guess and I think the problem comes from `rtol` and `atol` but I don't understand how to use it. I want to be able to check `if the guessed value + or - tolerance == the value of the dataset` can you help me ? My goal is to set 0.4 as tolerance so if I get [0.0,0.4] I set it as 0 and [0.6,1] I set it to 1

Comment: will there be any chance for -(negative)? as seems like it's more like a probability between 0 and 1. `"positive" if my_code + tolerance>= 1.0 else "Negative"`

Comment: @simpleApp following your input I did : ```for index, row in df.iloc[:15].iterrows():
   test = Feel(row['text'])
   if test.emotions().get('positivity') < 0.5 :
       if 0 == row['label']:
           correct = correct + 1
   elif test.emotions().get('positivity') > 0.5 :
       if 1 == row['label']:
           correct = correct + 1```